# Database connection from Java handler BIRT

Tags: database, datasource, handler, birt, actuate

I'm creating a rptlibrary to share with all the reports in my company. 
The library has an oda datasource created and shared to all reports. We want to do some querys from ReportEventAdapter.initialize() to the database to get information from the database. I can acces the datasource in the library in this way:

```
ReportDesignHandle rdh = (ReportDesignHandle)reportContext.getReportRunnable().getDesignHandle();
DesignSessionImpl ds = rdh.getModule().getSession();
String rsf = ds.getResourceFolder( );
LibraryHandle libhan = ds.openLibrary(rsf + "/my.rptlibrary" ).handle( );
DataSourceHandle datasource = libhan.findDataSource("myDS");
```

But once I have the datasource, there's no way to get a connection to the database from the datasource. The only way to do this, is creating a classic JDBC connection to the database using the data from the datasource? Is there any way to use a more elegant method to connect to the database from the java handler? Like using pooling, reusing the connection, etc..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate over dataset values in a report script event, thus if a dataset is defined with a JNDI URL, queries can take advantage of a connection pool.

However it is quite complicated. There is a full example [in this topic](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/34874-set-parameter-default-value-to-firsttop-value-in-the-list/): the script defined in "getDefaultValueList" event of the report parameter can be moved anywhere in the report and then initialize a global variable. In particular we could move it to "initialize" event, or to "beforeFactory" event (in your case "beforeFactory" is probably what you want).